# Is it advisable to call a WCF MSMQ Queued endpoint from a WPF client?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, architecture, msmq

I have messages that I want to send from multiple WPF client applications to a service that can be processed some time after being sent.
Because of expected intermittent connectivity issues between client and server and necessary down time for the service, I'm inclined to create a WCF service with a queued endpoint.  This has worked well for me in the past when the client machines were actually other servers and few in number.
I'm concerned about doing this with many client machines primarily because I think it will be difficult to monitor so many outgoing queues to confirm that no traffic is being trapped on the client machines.
Has anyone tried doing this before?
If so, would you recommend it? Why or why not?
Even if you haven't done it, can you think of other pitfalls beside the operational issue of monitoring all those outbound queues?

Answer (score 1):

Your question may be better worded as:

- *Should a system be rolled out with many nodes all using MSMQ?*

If so this is the essence of messaging and is what such systems are designed for irrespective of whether they are *JMS, Apache MQ, Websphere, SonicMQ,* or *MSMQ.*

Also, *"traffic is being trapped on the client machines"* - how do you define **trapped**?  Remember, the application may be quite happy for the message to be sitting locally for days before being forwarded to the remote host.  Messaging systems have timeouts generally for both reaching the destination and for the destination to process it.

I think you will be fine.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  In this particular instance, I need queuing, but it is not required to be queued on the client machine.  If I use MSMQ, there is an automatic client-side queue that can get stopped up because of connectivity, firewall, or quotas.  I'd rather not have operations monitor all those outbound queues.  I'm inclined to put a web service in front of the queued service and just display a "try later" error to the user when they lose connectivity.  This seems like it would be easier operationally.

Comment: @Adam47 No worries Adam.  Yes what you describe is something I've implemented recently. I use conventional blocking RPC via WCF from the client to the backend and once there I use a [Messaging Gateway pattern](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessagingGateway.html) that posts the requests to MSMQ.  I also used a [Request Reply pattern](http://www.eaipatterns.com/RequestReply.html) to make messaging look like RPC where necessary.  In this way, no MSMQ on the clients if not required. :)

Comment: @Adam47 _"there is an automatic client-side queue that can get stopped up because of connectivity, firewall, or quotas"_ - depends.  Use MSMQ **timeouts** to make messages expire where MSMQ will **automatically delete** the message.  Can firewalls block MSMQ? I would have thought MSMQ is on Windows's RPC layer